# Different elasticities of substitution

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, elasticity, elasticity-of-substitution

I have been reading into generalizations of the concept of elasticity of substitution for more goods/inputs and three main possibilities emerged:

- **Hicksian EOS**
- **Allen-Uzawa EOS**
- **Morishima EOS**

### HICKS

As I understand it, the Hicksian EOS is just an application of EOS on pairs of goods while holding others constant:

$$\sigma_{i,j}^{H} = \frac{\frac{\partial x_j/x_i}{x_j/x_i}}{\frac{\partial MRS_{i,j}}{MRS_{i,j}}}$$

where $MRS_{i,j} = MU_i/MU_j$. This can be computed for any $i$ and $j$.

The Hicksian EOS should therefore measure the EOS between two goods/inputs while others are considered constant.

However, further than this, things start to get weird. For example, I have stumbled upon this:

$$\sigma_{i,j}^{??} = \frac{\frac{\partial U}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial U}{\partial x_j}}{U \cdot \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}}$$

which has different implication than the previous elasticity, however it could still belong to Hicks?

### Allen-Uzawa

What concerns Allen-Uzawa EOS, it is strange how many different computations are offered there:

There is this:

$$ \sigma_{i,j}^{AU} = \frac{x_1 \frac{\partial U}{\partial x_1} + \dots x_n \frac{\partial U}{\partial x_n}}{\frac{\partial U}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial U}{\partial x_j}} \frac{F_{i,j}}{F} $$

where $F$ should be determinant and $F_{i,j}$ should be co-factor of $ \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$ in this determinant.

However, there is also this:

$$\sigma_{i,j} = \frac{XPD_{i,j}}{S_j}$$

where $XPD_{i,j}$ is cross-price elasticity of demand and $S_j$ is a share of $j$ input in total cost.

### Morishima

The last one is the weirdest:

$$\sigma_{i,j}^{M} = XPD_{j,i} - PD_{j,j} $$

Where $XPD$ is a crossprice elasticity of $j$ input according to $i$ price and $PD$ is own-price elasticity of demand.

### The question:

Right now, this seems to me to be a little too chaotic. Almost all of these almost seem to be completely unrelated. Then, there is of course the fact that in later definition the prices were brought in, while the original definition defines the elasticity of substitution as a propriety of utility function (concretely, the curvature of the indifference curve). So I am a little bit confused right now and I would like to ask the following:

- What do these **have in common**?
- How do they **differ**?
- How do those latter ones **really generalize** the former one?
- Do these serve as a measure **of how much** goods are substitutes or complements?
- Why the later ones **operate with prices** if the original is solely the propriety of a function?
- What would be the **connection between crossprice and EOS**?

Answer (score 1):

To everyone interested in the same problem, I have found a perfect article that goes into great length and detail explaining what are the interconnections and attributes/characteristics of each of these elasticities. It is a very good starting point and I can recommend it by all means.

It is by João Eustáquio de Lima (2000) [ALTERNATIVE DEFINITIONS OF ELASTICITY OF SUBSTITUTION: REVIEW AND APPLICATION](https://revistasober.org/journal/resr/article/5de93d7f0e8825317be31d41)